# Cannot get "apt-get install" or "apt install" to work on Kali Linux VM

Tags: apt, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently downloaded one of the [prebuilt Kali Linux VMs](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/) for VirtualBox (64 bit), and was trying to install the library python3-pip onto it. However, the commands "*apt-get install python3-pip*" and "*apt install python3-pip*" did not work, and kept returning the error of: "*E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate*". The same error occurs when trying to install any other package with apt-get.

Extra information:

- These commands were run with root
- I have the latest version of Kali Linux
- I currently do not have the latest version of VirtualBox (I have 6.1.6)
- I have tried editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it seems to have no effect

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061486/unable-to-locate-package-python-pip-when-trying-to-install-from-fresh-18-04-in)? It's saying that you have to add the universe category to your sources file.

Comment: @A4jNi1n I have tried this, however it doesn't seem to change anything. There is an error when running `apt update`, which is _E: Some Index Files Failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead._

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: Nope @AdminBee, my laptop is connected to wifi without a VPN or Proxy server